# Recuperar el número máximo de emparejamientos de dos equipos en SQL

Tags: sql

Estoy realizando unos ejercicios de consulta sql en base a un esquema relacional.

Preciso hacer las siguientes dos consultas:

- Obtén qué 2 equipos se han enfrentado más veces (con los ids de los equipos es suficiente)
- Obtén que 2 equipos se han enfrentado 11 veces (con los ids de los equipos es suficiente)

La sección correspondiente del esquema es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado con el siguiente código:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(Match_Id) AS Contador_Partidos,
    Team_1 AS Equipo_Local,
    Team_2 AS Equipo_Visitante
FROM
    MATCH
GROUP BY
    Equipo_Local,
    Equipo_Visitante
ORDER BY
    Contador_Partidos DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Pero no obtengo un resultado concluyente.
Gracias por vuestra ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: Pasa inserts into para poder probar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener los equipos que más veces se han enfrentado puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
select t1.team_name, t2.team_name, count(*) as partidos
from match m
inner join team t1
on m.team_1 = t1.team_id
inner join team t2
on m.team_2 = t2.team_id
group by t1.team_name, t2.team_name
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Utilizando la **cláusula inner join** relacionas las **tablas match** y **team** para obtener los datos del **equipo1** y posteriormente vuelves a utilizar el **inner join** para relacionar de nuevo las mismas tablas, pero esta vez para obtener los datos del **equipo2**. Después agrupas por los nombres de los equipos y ordenas descendentemente para obtener solamente el primer registro, seleccionando el **nombre del equipo1**, el **nombre del equipo2** y contando el total de veces que estos se han enfrentado.

Para obtener que dos equipos se han enfrentado **11** veces la consulta es similar a la anterior:

```
select t1.team_name, t2.team_name, count(*) as partidos
from match m
inner join team t1
on m.team_1 = t1.team_id
inner join team t2
on m.team_2 = t2.team_id
group by t1.team_name, t2.team_name
having count(*) = 11
```

Como ves aquí lo único que cambia respecto a la anterior consulta es que usas la **cláusula having** para obtener los equipos cuyo total de enfrentamientos es **11.**

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Fue de gran ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: @JuanArchidona que bueno que la respuesta te haya servido, podrias marcarla como aceptada, gracias